# Dealing with Changes in Column Names when dataloading (Access\SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Are there are some established\best practice ways when dealing with ever-changing column names, while the underlying data stays constant
The only solution that comes to mind is to write some code to recognize parts of the column names and constantly assign correct table names, are there any other best practice ways?
Source data quality control is not an option.

Comment: The established/best practice way to dealing with changing column names is not to have any. It works pretty well.

Comment: care to elaborate on *is not to have any.*? otherwise please delete your nonsence comment above

Comment: The only nonsence here is changing column names. Care to explain why they are changing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remember to read the FAQ about reputation and voting etc http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: @cularis Unfortunately in the real world you often get given these kind of nonsense tasks by clueless management.  I often find it is better to try and work out a way to do it or at least go half way than explain to a manager that he is an idiot.  It takes a certain amount of intelligence to understand that you are an idiot ;-)

Comment: @Ben Robinson, well it's employee's market right now. Lots of opportunities :)

Comment: Paul, you have said you were hoping for some other option (below). What kind of option were you hoping for? If you write about the real world problem in more detail, it is not impossible that some lateral solution may be suggested.

Comment: Remou, I understand now that I was overlooking some of the really evident options otlined below, for my specific case, it looks like the use of staging tables is probably going to resolve the issue, I was hoping to automate the hell out of Excel import into Access, with correct table names so that queries would work and all the data would be there, but it looks like the manual import is envitable, however through the use of staging tables+some import\quality control code I think I will be able to achieve, what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Typical ways

- If column names change, use ordinals instead eg col1, col2, col3
- If you have a finite set of different input formats, then have different imports (via a staging table)

If the order and/or datatype changes and/or it is truly random (which I doubt), then you have no reliable options in any language. This is not an IT problem...

Comment: Thank you for outlining the options, I was just hoping that there would be some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the ever changing column names are in some kind of spreadsheet or text file that you are importing and you are not dealing with a database where people keep going in and changing the column names.  If it is an automated import you only have 2 real options for mapping the file columns to database columns, column names which you have said are inconsistent or column positions which you haven't mentioned.  If they are inconsistent as well then you can't do it reliably, anything else you do would be educated guesswork and likely to fail often.

**EDIT**

Further to Tony Toews comment below, i have presumed that the import process is automated which is not clear from the question.  If it is in fact an interactive process and your users understand the concept then you could also do as he suggests and have a manual column mapping process as part of the import.

Comment: You presumption about spreadsheet is correct, I am sorry that I did not word the question more precisely. Thank you for outlining the options, I was just hoping that somebody came with some other way of dealing with this kind of incosistency.

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't have multiple incoming column headings map to one database column.  And use some kind of form which say 10 rows of data by column with your column name somehow selectable, maybe in combo boxes above each column, to make life easy for the user doing the import to match the columns.  Hmm, this is starting to sound like a bit of fun designing the UI.